# Screen flickering issue on Ubuntu 20.04.3LTC

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

I just changed my OS from lubuntu to Ubuntu 20.04.3 and I am having screen flickering issue. When I connect to an extent monitor, the screen flickers on the laptop screen but it's totally fine on the monitor.

The laptop is a Samsung NP355E5X with And E1-dual core APU and a 4gig DDR3 stick(upgraded by me)

Since the laptop is old, I'm not sure if this is a hardware issue on the laptop screen or a driver issue. Could someone please help me out?

Edit1:
So, right now, my setup is like my monitor is my primary display and my laptops inbuilt display is my secondary. When I have a bunch of apps open on my monitor, they don't get transferred to the laptop display when I remove the HDMI cable. When I plug it back in, the apps on the monitor are in the same state that I had previously left them in.

ibb.co/KyC0drN, ibb.co/YyGHnjq, ibb.co/80hJqn3 Here are the links to the images of the command outputs. My reputation isn't high enough to upload images over here @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio

Comment: Both Ubuntu & Lubuntu (an *official* [flavor of Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours)) use the same base so should be the same, **however** they do differ with regards default kernel stack choice if 20.04 or 20.04.1 media was used for install (Ubuntu Desktop defaulted to HWE, Lubuntu to GA for 20.04 & 20.04.1). Are you comparing the same kernel stacks?  (Ubuntu LTS releases like 20.04 have two kernel stacks you can opt to use) as if that differs, switching stack is likely your fix.  It may also help if you're specific as to what is flashing (is it the desktop itself, only parts? etc)

Comment: Please go ahead and instead of posting links to screen captures, copy-paste the text and format as code as appropriate.
That is the only way for others to copy portions of the output if needed. That helps others help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Could someone please help me out?**
Yes, somehow.

**I'm not sure if this is a hardware issue on the laptop screen or a driver issue.**
To assess this, you could boot from a live USB, Ubuntu 20.04.3, with your monitor plugged in. If this leads to problems, you could try plugging the monitor after you booted.

In the meantime, please post the output of

```
$ uname -a
$ hwinfo --monitor --gfxcard
$ wmctrl -m
```

with the monitor plugged in, and in your Ubuntu OS, not the Live USB.
You may need to install `sudo apt install hwinfo`.

Also post the behaviour you see when you alternate plugging/unplugging the monitor.

Comment: So, right now, my setup is like my monitor is my primary display and my laptops inbuilt display is my secondary. When I have a bunch of apps open on my monitor, they don't get transferred to the laptop display when I remove the HDMI cable. When I plug it back in, the apps on the monitor are in the same state that I had previously left them in.

Comment: https://ibb.co/KyC0drN,
https://ibb.co/YyGHnjq,
https://ibb.co/80hJqn3   Here are the links to the images of the command outputs. My reputation isn't high enough to upload images over here @sancho.s ReinstateMonicaCellio

Comment: @Trijwal - Please post all this as part of the question, and copy-paste text and format as code when suitable.
That is a minimal way of helping others help you.

Comment: Done. Thanks @sancho